# Short story about a spaceship crew member who was half-man, half-bee and had an innate sense of how to get home, no matter where they were

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, space

This story was in a book of science-fiction short stories. Maybe around the late '80s early '90s.

I don’t I don’t remember much from the specific story, other than that I believe a crew was somehow stranded in space in their ship, and among them was a man crossbred with genes from a bee. This led to him being fairly mentally handicapped, so he couldn’t do much, but he had an innate sense of how to get home and where home was, no matter where, even light years away, and that was his purpose. I could be wrong.

I probably am wrong about details of which I realize there are not many. Sorry and thank you.